# Multiple images not sharing with Social Share Plugin Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: cordova

I am developing phonegap application and used the Social Share Plugin Cordova/Phonegap to share Post and  Images on Facebook. But when I tried to shared multiple images its not working and giving error.

I am passing multiple images as array as below,

```
['image1','image2']
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: Which version of the plugin are you using? Can you share the exact line you are using?

Comment: I have downloaded from the below URl, https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin               and                                                                                                                                                           My code :  window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaFacebook('message', null,['image1','image2']);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the documentation [from the plugin github page](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin#sharing-multiple-images-or-other-files):

```
// sharing multiple images via Facebook (you can mix protocols and file locations)
window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaFacebook(
  'Optional message, may be ignored by Facebook app',
  ['https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo4w.png','www/image.gif'],
  null);
```

Here you indicated (in comment) that you did the following:

```
window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaFacebook('message', null,['image1','image2']);
```

I think you made a mistake in the order of your parameters: it shoud be message then images array then null:

```
window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaFacebook('message', ['image1','image2'], null);
```